# Como adicionar chave primaria SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Bom dia! talvez seja simples minha dúvida, mas... gostaria de saber como adicionar chave primária numa tabela não estando no momento de criação (CREATE), sei que ao acessar a tabela no "object explorer" na opção "design" é possível facilmente com dois click's... mas gostaria saber mesmo como fazer via código. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute o seguinte código de alteração da tabela.

```
ALTER TABLE NOME_DA_TABELA ADD PRIMARY KEY (NOME_DO_CAMPO)
```

Comment: ótimo, o que eu precisava... muito obrigado!